# String processing in R (find and replace)

Tags: r, string

This is an example of my `data.frame`

```
no string
1  abc&URL_drf
2  abcdef&URL_efg
```

I need to replace word `*&URL` with `""`. So, I need a this result

```
no string
1 _drf
2 _efg
```

In case of Excel, I can easily make this result using `'*&URL'` in 'find and replace' function.
However, I cannot look for effective method in R.

In R, my approach is below.

First, I have split string using `strsplit(df$string, "&URL")` and then I have selected second column. I think that it is not a effective way.

Is there a any effective method?

Comment: I can't tell you about R exactly, but if this language provides regular expression functions you could use `[0-9]+\s+(.+&URL)` and remove the content from the start & end indices of group 1.

Comment: I think `sapply(strsplit(df[[2]], "URL"), "[", 2)` may be pretty fast.  Can you define effective?

Comment: @Tyler Rinker/ I think that effectiveness is the 'simple and fast'. Your approach is impressive. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# data
df <- read.table(text="no string
1  abc&URL_drf
2  abcdef&URL_efg", header=T, as.is=T)

# `gsub` function is to substitute the unwanted string with nothing, 
# thus the `""`. The pattern of unwanted string was written in 
# regular expressions.

df$string <- gsub("[a-z]+(&URL)", "", df$string)
# you get
  no string
1  1   _drf
2  2   _efg
```

Comment: Using `[0-9]+\s+(.+&URL)` and removing group 1 would also allow characters other than a-z as the prefix.

Comment: Why do you create a group (`(&URL)`)?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, we could remove `()` and it will return the same result. Just that `()` is not working at harm s way and is easy to the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [grep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)  function .

The grep function takes your regex as the first argument, and the input vector as the second argument.If you pass value=TRUE, then grep returns a vector with copies of the actual elements in the input vector that could be (partially) matched.

so in your case

```
grep("[a-z]+(&URL)", df$col, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
df <- transform(df, string = sub(".*&URL", "", string))

#  no string
# 1  1   _drf
# 2  2   _efg
```